# Simple Expression in apache-camel uri

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm new to apache-camel and know i met a problem.
I want to use simple expressions in my uri definition, but i don't know how.

For example:

```
from("foo://bar").to("foo://bar?var=${header.varName}");
```

Is there a way to use such expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bernhard

http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Use the Recipient List EIP pattern, which allows you to compute the dynamic URI using an Expression.
For example using the Simple expression language as shown below:

```
recipientList(simple("freemarker://templateHome/${body.templateName}.ftl"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just wondering why i haven't found that :-)

Comment: looks like this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the "CamelXsltResourceUri" property in the header.

```
.setHeader("CamelXsltResourceUri",simple("xslt:<path>/<to>/<template>"))
```

> "recipientList(simple("freemarker://templateHome/${body.templateName}.ftl"))"

The selected answer did not work for me since I had to use a custom uriresolver

Answer (score 0):

Use `toD()` then dynamic uri can be used. recipientlist is for multiple destinations, not the correct EIP.

However you may need to avoid creating too many different URLs with your `simple()` expression. See: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/toD-eip.html