# Apache Camel avoid duplicating options across similar XML routes

Tags: java, apache-camel, el

I have some Apache Camel routes with many options, like this one:

```
<from uri="sftp://user@host:22/path?
  password=vvvvv;delay=3000&amp;streamDownload=true&amp;
  delete=true&amp;idempotent=true&amp;idempotentRepository=#jpaStore&amp;
  inProgressRepository=#jpaStore"/>
```

This isn't so bad, but I have six other routes with the same options but different paths. I'd like to put all the options in a constant to avoid duplication:

```
<from uri="sftp://user@host:22/path?OPTIONS"/>
```

I might be able to use [Camel EL](http://camel.apache.org/el.html) to accomplish this, but none of the examples show it, and my attempts to guess the syntax aren't working.

I create a Spring bean like this:

```
<bean id="myoptions" class="java.lang.String">
  <constructor-arg value="allmyoptions"/>
</bean>
```

And try to refer to it like this:

```
<from uri="sftp://user@host:22/path?${myoptions}"/>
```

But I get an error:

> There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{${myoptions}=}]

This question, [Simple Expression in apache-camel uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035194/simple-expression-in-apache-camel-uri), is attempting something similar, but they use Java DSL and my routes are configured in XML.

Does anyone know a good way to avoid duplicating all this options across routes?

Answer (score 3):

From this page, [How do I use Spring Property Placeholder with Camel XML](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html), I read that "We do NOT yet support the ${something} notation inside arbitrary Camel XML." This said, they suggest various workarounds on this page, [Properties](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html).

What worked for me was to configure a `BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` as follows:

```
<bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:myproperties.properties"/>
</bean>
```

In the properties file I have:

```
OPTIONS=password=vvvvv;delay=3000&streamDownload=true&delete=true&idepotent=true&idempotentRepository=#jpaStore&inProgressRepository=#jpaStore
```

This allows me to use both the Spring property placeholder notation `${}` and the Camel placeholder notation with `{{ }}`:

```
<from uri="sftp://user@host:22/path?{{OPTIONS}}"/>
```

One gotcha is that I needed to get rid of my encoded ampersands in the properties file, replacing `&amp;` with just `&`.

See also:

- Answer: [How to use a dynamic URI in From()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369926/201891)
- Documentation: [How do I use Spring Property Placeholder with Camel XML](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html)
- Documentation: [Properties](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html)